# How To Read Windows.edb file?

Tags: c++, python, database, edb

I am wanting to create a script/software that can read/access, then query an edb database file. I am looking at the Windows Indexing file which comes in the form of an edb file. Python doesn't seem to have any modules that I could use to query the database. Do any other languages, such as C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a special library for accessing `.edb` files in C: `libesedb`. They have a repository on Google Code: https://code.google.com/p/libesedb/. Check out their wiki for examples: https://code.google.com/p/libesedb/wiki/libesedb.

**Update:**

This is the new url: https://github.com/libyal/libesedb

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Iron Python and CLR? If so, check out ManagedEsent and Esedb.
http://managedesent.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Esedb/

C Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg269259(v=exchg.10).aspx

-martin